# How to update the lookup field with passing the string value of name?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, developer

### This line doesn't update

```
    adobeevent.LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Status__c = userNode.getAttributeValue('Name', null);

LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Status__c field is the lookup field
Name is the text field


how to insert name field into lookup field.
```

Thanks,
vishnu

Answer (score 0):

Set the Id of the lookup record. If you dont have the id, query the sobject using the name attribute and then set it on the adobeevent object

```
adobeevent.LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Status__c = 'Id of the lookup sobject record'
```

Comment: thanks for giving the response but here i'm not inserting the sObject here i'm inserting the external data into salesforce

Comment: not sure if i understand you correctly, even if you insert external data will it not have an Id?